# How to read a Sitecore Update package?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

Is it possible to read a Sitecore .update package programatically and get a list of items and their commands?

For example, Item ID : XXXXXXX Command: ChangedItems, 
             Item ID : XXXXXUYYI Command: AddedItems
             ......... and so on

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `Sitecore.Update.dll`

And use something like this.

```
using Sitecore.Update.Installer;
using Sitecore.Update.Installer.Utils;

....

DiffInstaller installer = new DiffInstaller(UpgradeAction.Upgrade);
MetadataView view = UpdateHelper.LoadMetadata("C:\\projects\\mySitecore\\Source\\Website\\sitecore\\admin\\Packages\\Mypackage.update");
```

View contains now the metaData. Probably there are more options somewhere there to find the items. See [Package installer script](https://github.com/jbluemink/Sitecore-Admin-Scripts-for-Development-and-Deploying/blob/master/InstallUpdatePackage.aspx) and [HedgehogDevelopment SitecorePackageDeployer](https://github.com/HedgehogDevelopment/SitecorePackageDeployer) for some example code. But at the end an .update package is just a zip file. so if the API is not enough treat the file like a zip.

Comment: I have been checking Siteore.Update.dll for some days now without any luck. I am unable to find an option that will accept .update package and return the item IDs and their respective commands. It would be great if there is any such utility. Also, I hope I understand your last suggestion correctly. You mean to say that I should try reading the .update file like a .zip file using a zip utility like DotZip etc. And then try to read the XML files to get the item ID and command. Am I correct?

Comment: That metadata view class that Jan suggested looks promising. Also there is PackageReader inside the Sitecore.Update.dll, did you take a look at that?